# Proving/finding counterexamples on subspace statements

Tags: linear-algebra

> True/False statements: prove or give a counterexample
>
> **1)** If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are free subsets of the (finite) vectorspace $V$ then the union $\alpha \ \cup \ \beta$ is also free.
>
> **2)** If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, $\alpha$ is a basis of $U$ and $\beta$ is a basis of $W$ then $\alpha \ \cap \ \beta$ is a basis for $U \ \cap \ W$.

**1)** I suspect it is false, given that this statement is closely related to the fact that the union of two subspaces does not need to yield a subspace. As a counterexample I took the following independent subsets

$$\alpha = \{ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}, \quad \beta = \{ (2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$$

But its union $\alpha \ \cup \ \beta = \{ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$ is clearly not linearly independent.

**2)** I suspect this statement is wrong but I am struggling to find a counterexample. I am looking for the simplest one could find; I thought of $V= \Bbb R^2$, $U = \{ (x, 0) | x \in \Bbb R\}$ and $W = \{ (0, y) | y \in \Bbb R\}$ but does not work. I also thought of $V= \Bbb R^3$ and intersecting two planes (say $xy$ and $xz$) but the intersection is $x$ which is a basis for the intersection subspace so it doesn not work either.

Could you help me find a counterexample? :)

Comment: What is a "free" subset of a vector space?  Statement $2$ is nonsense....even for one dimensional spaces.  Just take any two  (distinct) bases for $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over itself.

Comment: Free means linearly independent. Statement 2: do you mean that we can simply take any two distinct bases for $\Bbb R$ (say $\alpha = \{1\}$ and $\beta = \{3\}$) and state that $\alpha \cap \beta = \{0\}$, which is of course not a valid basis?

Comment: Ok...but then the same counterexample applies.  Take any two distinct (and non-zero) real numbers, considering $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over itself.

Comment: @lulu could you please give me more details on the counterexample for 2)? The example I gave is not a counterexample: the intersection is empty so a basis for the intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Taking your example, $\alpha =\{1\}$, $\beta =\{3\}$, then both $\alpha, \beta$ generate all of $\mathbb R$.  The intersection of $\mathbb R$ with itself is all of $\mathbb R$, but the two bases do not intersect.  The empty set is not a basis of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ahh so just let me check my understanding. We take $V=\Bbb R$. Then we take $U=span\{x | x \in R \} = W$ (there is no statement saying that $U,W$ cannot be equal, so it is OK). Then we take $\alpha =\{1\}$ and $\beta =\{3\}$ as bases of $U$ and $W$ respectively. We conclude that $\alpha \cap \beta = \{0\}$ but $U \cap W = span\{x | x \in R \} \neq \{0\}$. Agree? :)

Comment: Almost the intersection of $\{\alpha\}$ and $\{\beta\}$ is empty, not $\{0\}$.

Comment: Alright so I should have written $\alpha \cap \beta = \emptyset$ and $U \cap W = span\{x | x \in R \} \neq  \emptyset$ instead.

Comment: I'd prefer to see $\{\alpha\}\cap \{\beta\}=\emptyset$.  Sets can intersect, numbers can't.